# Hop extracts...

Tags: hops

Do you use them?
How do you use them?
How can I get some?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used them. The amount of hops I need for my beers is never high enough to justify going for the extract. But if I wanted to make a super-high IBU high-gravity monster, I'd think about it.

[Northern Brewer sells them](http://www.northernbrewer.com/brewing/brewing-ingredients/hops/hopshot/hopshot.html). Seems like you can add it at any time during the boil. And the NB site links to a calculator you can use to determine IBUs.